# Online collocations search engine?

Tags: discussion, online-resources

What's the best collocations search website you've used?

I recall there being one associated with Oxford but can no longer find it. It returned results from classical and modern English sources, including some copyrighted archive collections (newspaper archives, literature archives, ...).

It had a very detailed search UI where you could specify phrase length, age, and similar.

Comment: Resource requests are not actually about the language, and are (on this site) accommodated on its Meta.ELU.

Comment: The most relevant meta question is [Is there a tool that provides/suggests words that come before or after a word?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13254/191178). Do the resources there meet your needs?

Comment: Covered at the resources list.

Comment: If you have access to the OED, a list of all examples containing a given lemma followed by a KWIC sort would do precisely that, as well as containing examples of all idioms and constructions the lexical item participates in.